# Magento 2 How to apply jquery for getting input text value in checkout page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, knockout.js, magento2

I want to get input text value in checkout page.

I have tried to apply jquery in checkout page but it didn't work it. I have also worked with pure javascript but it also didn't work.

Jquery not working because checkout page working only knockout js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
        jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery("#shipping-new-address-form input[name='vat_id']").keyup(function(e) {
                alert("test");
            });
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

This code is working fine on console.

Please help me and solve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try the below code and it should work as i am already using something like this and it is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#shipping-new-address-form input[name="vat_id"]', function(e) {
                        alert("test");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @OlivierVandeVelde Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 works with requireJS library, so you need to use "require"/"define" function to receive the jquery.

I think that you want to change the shipping behavior, so, you can do a fallback of shipping.js from Magento_Checkout module and add your code there.

```
your-theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

Comment: Thank for the reply